# How can I read the response using the jersey client

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have seen examples (and they work with other objects, like String)

[How to get list<String> as response from jersey2 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313767/how-to-get-liststring-as-response-from-jersey2-client)

So, I have a method that response to my endpoint like this:

```
 return Response.ok(new CustomDto<>(param1, param2)).build();
```

You can notice the `<>`

so the class lookes like this:

```
public class CustomDto<T extends OtherDto> extends PaginatorDto<T> {
...
}
```

So for my test I did this...

```
CustomDto resultPaginator = response.readEntity(CustomDto.class);
```

So I get this error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `CustomDto` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

The class has no basic constructor (and I cannot add one)

Any idea how to get the results using this class?

Thanks

Comment: Can you alter the class? If so, use a `@JsonCreator` constructor. If not, use a Jackson Mixin.

Comment: Hello, no, I cannot alter the class

Comment: could you be more specific or give an example?

Comment: https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue/

Comment: Why did you put the bounty? Did you not figure out how to do it with the Mixin examples I linked to? Or does it not work, even with the Mixin?

Comment: I dont know how to do without modifying the constructor

Comment: Use the Mixin. You don't need to modify the constructor. You make a separate Mixin class. Look at the link.

Comment: Hey, so did you get it to work? Do you have any follow up questions?